# Welcoming Cipher Puzzle

Tags: cipher

Please leave this puzzle for users with less than 200 rep.

Each of the following lines until the last provides a significant clue for solving the next cipher.

Letters have a natural order

C SEA WRA SA VTN YRE RP O RG SSE VI E UB TT H NE XE T PIC H RE SI

uifpwoehuwevjhtuxjpuhbma

531532133533154535414415

Comment: I think this is a nice idea. Not sure why the early downvote?

Comment: @Stiv Thanks, it's the nature of a community-run site I guess

Comment: +1 for "Please leave this puzzle for users with less than 100 rep." :)

Comment: But a new user from another active site will have 101 reps ><

Comment: Leave it for <200 rep people.

Comment: Oh? I wasn't aware of that. Okay sure.

Comment: I have 221, just barely over the cap. *Starts singing It Sucks to be Me from Avenue Q*

Comment: And @ManojKumar has 194 rep, right below the cap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, the first cipher is a

> Transposition cipher. I'm not actually sure which: I looked at the frequency of the letters, and determined it was probably a transposition cipher on a message in english. Then I noticed by chance the word "Cipher" and "Caesar", which were both "locally permuted" (i.e. if you consider the letters of a word in the plaintext message, then they will be 'close' in the ciphertext). From there I read the cipher from left to right, and guessed the plaintext).

and the ciphertext decodes to

> Caesar wasn't very progressive but the next cipher is

The second cipher is

> a progressive Caesar cipher, where the first 3 letters are shifted by 1, the next 3 by 2, the next 3 by 3$\dots$

and the ciphertext decodes to

> The numbers are coordinates

The last cipher is a

> Polybius cypher with key:
>  ABCDE
>  FGHIJ
>  KLMNO
>  PQRST
>  UVWXY

which yields

> Welcome to PSE

Oh, and thanks for

> the warm welcome :)

Comment: Good job :) The first cipher is an Alphabetical Disorder Cipher. Simply order each group of letters alphabetically.

Comment: Nice answer, well presented again!